# Can we connect Facebook/ Meta Ads with Apache Beam or any other real-time streaming service to get real time data from Facebook ads to Bigquery

Tags: facebook-graph-api, google-bigquery, apache-beam, facebook-marketing-api

How can I bring real-time streaming data from Meta Ads and stream it into bigquery or the desired sink I want using Apache Beam or any connector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know anything about Meta Ads subscriptions, but you could [write your own streaming source](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/developing-io-overview/) or run a process that subscribes to the ad data and publishes to pubsub (or another system like kafka) and process it in an Apache Beam pipeline.